# Footer con animación y desplazamiento horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Necesito poder generar un movimiento en el footer de mi página web, actualmente estoy usando HTML 5 y Bootstrap (soy bastante nuevo en lo que es desarrollo de páginas), me pidieron que el footer genere un efecto como de fade cuando el cursor pase encima del footer(oscurecerse de forma leve pero no tanto como para desaparecer) y ademas que al pasar el cursor por encima del footer se desplace de forma horizontal como un leve movimiento de sacudida y que vuelva a su punto original.

Adjunto el código del footer:

```css
/* Footer */

#footer {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4rem 0 2rem 0;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#footer a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

#footer .copyright {
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  #footer {
    padding: 3rem 0 1rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="icons">
      <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope-o"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
    &copy; Benjamin Galdames Aracena. Todos Los Derechos Reservados.
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hola Benjamín, bienvenido. Te invito a reformular tu pregunta de manera que sea de ayuda para ti mismo el aprender lo que necesitas hacer, de momento parece más bien un requerimiento poco específico. Cuando y como el efecto fade? Cuando y como el efecto de desplazamiento?. De momento te comento que parecen cosas que podrías hacer con CSS3 animations. Saludos.

Comment: Listo acabo de especificar mejor el efecto y el tipo de movimiento, muchas gracias!

Comment: Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres que se mueva/anime: todo el footer o sólo el enlace cuando pasas por encima?